# what is the differene between "class" and "struct"?

Tags: c++, class, struct

When writing C++ code, what is the difference between using `class` and `struct`?

```
class Foo final { };
```

vs.

```
struct Bar final { };
```

When should I prefer one over the other?  Is this merely a choice of programming/coding style?

Comment: What have your books, tutorials or class told you about it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I can't find anything in my books that explains **why** I would want to use one over the other; it appears that they are practically identical.

Comment: That's because they *are* practically identical. The only difference between a `struct` and a `class` is the default visibility. A `struct` is by default `public`, while a class is by default `private`. Which one to choose very much depends on that. *Unless* you're making a C-compatible interface, and need your header file and structures to be compatible with C, in which case you need to use `struct` (and POD structures only, using non-C++ types for the members variables and no member functions).

Comment: A common convention is to use `struct` when you don't need anything other than public non-static member variables. Or when writing small helper types for templates, where `public` would waste space.

Comment: In addition to what @SomeProgrammerDude said, there's *one* other difference. When you inherit from a `struct` the default is `public` inheritance and when you inherit from a `class` the default is `private` inheritance.

Answer (score -5):

A `struct` simply defines the layout of a piece of storage.

A `class` is a dynamically-allocated "thing" which can have methods ... it can *do* things.

Comment: Totally inaccurate, I'm sorry to say.

Comment: You can have methods in a `struct`, and both can be allocated statically or dynamically.

Comment: Dead wrong. ...